# How could I set C and gamma value for SVM in Matlab

Tags: matlab, svm, hyperparameters, predefined-variables

I trt to train a pre-designed SVM with RBF kernel. I want to fix the C and gamma value before train. I use

```
Mdl = fitcsvm(Xapp,Yapp,'KernelFunction','rbf','KernelScale', 1,'BoxConstraint', 1,...);
```

But after training, the C(BoxConstraint) and gamma(KernelScale) are changed.
How could I fix them?

There are two links show how could they change the parameters. But I don't know if they could fix them until train finished.
[1](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/507787-how-can-i-add-the-c-parameter-as-a-single-value-in-fitcsvm)
[2](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/336748-support-vector-machine-parameters-matlab)

Answer (score 0):

Set 'OptimizeHyperparameters' as 'none' instead of 'auto'